# Files getting corrupted using apex:inputFile

Tags: attachment, file-processing, apexinputfile

I am using apex:inputFile to upload documents in a vf page, but sometimes the file is getting saved as .dat file. This is not happening always. I am not rerendering the apex:inputfile and we are not using salesforce for outlook, so I've ruled out the rtf file format issue.

What could be the issue?

Comment: Could you post your code? Are you getting the mime type for the file?